# Swift UITabBarController smooth hiding with animation

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

```
extension UITabBarController {
    @objc func hideTabBarAndUpdateFrames() {
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                 width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                 height: self.view.frame.height + self.tabBar.bounds.size.height)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.tabBar.isHidden = true
            self.tabBar.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.maxY
        }
    }
    
    @objc func showTabBarAndUpdateFrames() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                     y: self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                     width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                     height: self.view.frame.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height)
            self.tabBar.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.tabBar.frame.height
            self.tabBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        self.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

I’m trying to add `animation` to my `tabBarController` when it’s hidden. It works, but when the view is scrolled, the `tabBar` disappears and leaves behind empty white space. After scrolling finishes, the tab bar reappears.

How can I remove the white space that appears when the tab bar is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the actual position & size of tabbar.
It can return messy result.

Try using [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cgaffinetransform)

Example:

```
// If u set the duration of animation too low, it can be glitchy
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.tabBar.isHidden = true
    // self.tabBar.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.maxY
    let deltaY = self.view.frame.maxY
    self.tabBar.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: deltaY)
}

// To reset all transform
self.tabBar.transform = .identity
```

Hope that it will help you to solve the issue.